# How to unescape semicolon output in double quoted dig/nslookup output?

Tags: escape-characters, dig, nslookup

When querying for a TXT DNS record that contains a semicolon (;) using both `dig` and `nslookup` version 9.8.3-P1, its output of the text record is in double quoted output format:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
host._domainkey.domain.tld  text = "v=DKIM1\;k=rsa\;p=MIGf...IDAQAB\;"
```

[**Why** dig does show the ; as \; is explained at the FreeBSD mailing list in 2008](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2008-December/001117.html).

[Somewhere between 9.8 and 9.9 versions semicolons in quoted text are not escaped any longer](http://bind-users-forum.2342410.n4.nabble.com/semicolons-in-dig-output-td3199.html).

I don't want to upgrading Mac OS X 10.9. Installing a package with `brew` as an option.

How can I unescape the double quoted output from `dig` and/or `nslookup` answers permanently without having to change my query command?

Answer (score 1):

```
dig txt domain.example.com | sed 's/\\;/;/g
```